# How to add styles to a button that is created when clicking another button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this button that is loaded whenever u click another button(so its not loaded on startup without me doing anything)

```
<button type='button' id='testbtn' 
onclick='testfunction()' onload='testload()' 
class='testbtnclass'>btn</button>
```

This is my function:

```
 function testload() {

alert("onload worked");
 /*what i want to archieve within this function later is to change the
 css of the button but for now i just want to call this function onload of 
 the button, which it doesnt/*
}
```

My question is now, how can i/should i do to get this function to run whenever this button is loaded?

Comment: Jquery allowed or only javascript ?

Comment: So you have `btnA`, when you click on it it generates `btnB`, and then you want to fire an event when you created `btnB`?

Comment: why not do it on `document.onload` ? it wil be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` is not  supported by `button` tag so you need to do it either as other answer telling or with

```
document.onload =function(){

  //change the css of that button or call function you want 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can create a css class example:

```
.buttonStyle{ background-color: red };
```

Then you can get your button and add this class

```
var button = document.getElementById("testbtn");
button.className = button.className + " buttonStyle";
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery you can do just the following:

```
$( "button" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use event delegation of jQuery. With this technique, it doesnt matter if the button gets generated after DOM is loaded.

```
$('body').on('click', '.generated_btn', function() {
    //here you can change css
});
```

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

More information: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/